# Multi-month view for Outlook 2007 calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar

Is there any way (plugins are acceptable) to have multiple months in the same view?  I'm looking for something that provides the same thing as the built-in month view, only showing more than one month at a time.

Comment: And having [many months](http://i.imgur.com/ycjbB.png) in the side panel isn't what you want?

Comment: @Zoredache No, I want to see where I've got items on my calendar and not just the month layouts.  Even 2-3 months in a single view will make me happy.

Answer (score 1):

if you highlight multiple months on the mini calendar at left, you can see all highlighted days in the large display, but the more you put in, the smaller it becomes

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like it's capped at about 6 weeks.  I'm looking for something more like 4-6 months.  Unless I'm missing something, which admittedly is certainly not outside the realm of possibility today...

Answer (score 0):

First, open the Navigation Pane on the left. Then drag the bottom right corner to enlarge the box. Then click and drag to highlight multiple days, weeks, and months.

I am sorry to inform you that this is the closest you can get. With the release of Office 2010, [people are still contacting Microsoft, upset that they can't do more than "Month" view](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/outlook-2010-calendar-year-view/ed827d7d-b6e7-4e70-bb39-8dbd86de94eb). In fact, the common consensus seems to be there should be a "Year" view..

Comment: See my comment to Lawrence's answer.

Comment: I edited it a little for ya.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to view/print upcoming activities months in advance, you might want to check out the Calendar Printing Assistant for Microsoft Outlook 2007 application from Microsoft.